# Changes the UIView display by clicking on the button in a child view

Tags: ios

I have a UIView initialized in CreateAccountViewController

```
import UIKit

class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func btnAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
        let subview = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        self.addview.addSubview(subview)

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var addview: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I want to add a new UUBiew for this UIView when I click on the btn button in UIView Slide
    I implemented as below and get

> 1 addview error = nil.

Can someone help me?

```
import UIKit

class Slide: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTen: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHinhAnh: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        let subview = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Test", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Test
        let Storyboard=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let scr=Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateAccount") as! CreateAccountViewController
        scr.addview.addSubview(subview)

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNoiDung: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have created XIB files for `Slide` and `Test`. You can use protocol delegate method to achieve your code. Create protocol method of Slide view and by creating delegate you can access `btn` tap in view controller by calling same delegate protocol method.

```
class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController, SlideDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var addview: UIView!

    // Create Global Variable to access in delegate method of SlideDelegate
     var slideView: Slide?

    @IBAction func btnAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
        slideView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as? Slide
        slideView?.delegate = self
        self.addview.addSubview(slideView!)
    }

    func add(view: Test) {
        if slideView != nil {
            slideView?.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Create protocol as follows;

```
protocol SlideDelegate: class {
    func add(view: Test)
}


class Slide: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTen: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHinhAnh: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtNoiDung: UILabel!

    weak var delegate: SlideDelegate?

    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        let subview = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Test", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! Test

        if let selfDelegate = delegate {
            // Call delegate method which will notify your view controller to add sub view
            selfDelegate.add(view: subview)
        }
    }
}
```